# Copy content of array in arduino programming

Tags: arrays, arduino

This may be an easy question, but i couldn't find out how to do this. Im programming for arduino and im trying to copy the content from one array to another. I've programmed in python before and hoped that this would work, but it didn't.

```
int myArray1[] = {0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11};
int myArray2[] = {0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10};
int myArray3[] = {0, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10};

int newArray[] = myArray2;
```

I wanted to only have to change one place in my code, which of the first three arrays i want my new array to take values from. Do anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate over the array, so

```
Declare the array here (see answer text)
byte i;
for (i=0; i<(sizeof(myArray2)/sizeof(int)); i++)
{
  newArray[i] = myArray2[i];
}
```

Now, for the declaration of newArray. The best thing is to create a "statically" allocated variable: so you should write

```
int myArray1[] = {0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11};
int myArray2[] = {0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10};
int myArray3[] = {0, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10};
int newArray[7];
```

The size should be the MAXIMUM size you need.

If allocating statically is not an option, you can allocate it dYnamically:

```
int* newArray= NULL;
...
newArray = new int [sizeof(myArray2)/sizeof(int)];
... use the array ...
delete[] newArray;
```

In this case you MUST delete the array when you are done using it (and definitely you MUST destroy it before a new `new`).

I highly suggest you the first approach

Answer (score 0):

From the description, it sounds like you could use a pointer to the arrays to select which one to use.

Declare a pointer:

```
int *use_array;
```

And then assign one of the existing arrays to it:

```
use_array = my_array1;
```

Then reference the array with use_array

```
use_array[2] = ... // whatever
```

Be very, *very*, careful not to run off the end of the array. If the arrays are actually variable lengths, then you have more book-keeping to do. This is very low level stuff, but standard C.

If you *really* want to move bytes around instead of changing a single pointer, then look into the `memcpy` function from the AVR libc library.

Have fun!